# Problemas al mandar a llamar una constante como método en PHP

Tags: php, mvc

buen día. El problema que tengo es el siguiente:
Tengo un método que se llama `index()`, y quiero acceder a el con la constante definida como `ACCION_PRINCIPAL`.

Tengo este código. tengo mi archivo `config.php` donde defino las constante:

```
<?php
define("CONTROLADOR_PRINCIPAL", "Vehiculos");
define("ACCION_PRINCIPAL", "index");
```

Tengo un archivo `routes.php` donde tengo funciones para cargar el controlador y la acción:

```
<?php

function cargarControlador($controlador)
{
  $nombreControlador = ucwords($controlador) . "Controller";
  $archivoControlador = "controller/" . ucwords($controlador) . ".php";

  if (!is_file($archivoControlador)) {
    $archivoControlador = "controller/" . CONTROLADOR_PRINCIPAL . ".php";
  }

  require_once $archivoControlador;

  $control = new $nombreControlador();
  return $control;
}

function cargarAccion($controlador, $accion)
{
  if (isset($_GET["a"]) && method_exists($controlador, $accion)) {

    $controlador->$accion();
  } else {
    $controlador->ACCION_PRINCIPAL();
  }
}
```

y en mi archivo `index.php` mando a llamar todos los archivos que necesito

```
<?php
require_once "config/config.php";
include_once "core/routes.php";
require_once "config/database.php";
require_once "controller/Vehiculos.php";
```

y aquí es donde cargo los controladores y los métodos (dentro del mismo archivo `index.php`):

```
if (isset($_GET["c"])) {

 $controlador = cargarControlador($_GET["c"]);

 if (isset($_GET["a"])) {
   cargarAccion($controlador, $_GET["a"]);
 } else {
   cargarAccion($controlador, ACCION_PRINCIPAL);
 }
} else {

 $controlador = cargarControlador(CONTROLADOR_PRINCIPAL);
 cargarAccion(CONTROLADOR_PRINCIPAL, ACCION_PRINCIPAL);
}
```

Esto lo hago para que en caso de que no haya un controlador, me cargue el principal (Vehiculos), y en caso de que no haya un método cargue el predeterminado (index).

si ingreso esta URL:

```
http://localhost/classmvc/index.php?c=Vehiculos&a=index
```

todo carga como debe, ya que estoy pasando parámetros correctos, pero cuando paso parámetros incorrectos (Que es cuando debería cargar los predeterminados), ocurre un error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method VehiculosController::ACCION_PRINCIPAL() . . .
```

A lo que yo entiendo, esto es debido a que en el archivo de `routes.php`, cuando hago:

```
$controlador->ACCION_PRINCIPAL();
```

toma `ACCION_PRINCIPAL` como el nombre del método, y no como la constante que quiero llamar.

ya cambié esa línea por un

```
$controlador->index();
```

y todo funciona, pero lo que quiero es mandar a llamar a la constante.

Alguien puede ayudarme con eso?

Comment: Prueba con `$controlador->{ACCION_PRINCIPAL}();`

Answer (score 0):

En ese caso Php lo interpreta literal. Para evitar ese problema podrías usar el método [**call_user_func**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.call-user-func.php).

```
call_user_func([$controlador, ACCION_PRINCIPAL]);
```